# Is it possible to express "$P\leftrightarrow Q$" as a formula in $\to,\neg$ with $P$ only appearing once?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I want to write a propositional logic formula for the biconditional that only uses one side of the biconditional once in the formula. I expect it is impossible, but can anyone think of a proof? There are many formulas for the biconditional:

\begin{align}P\leftrightarrow Q&\equiv(P\to Q)\wedge(Q\to P)\\
&\equiv(P\vee Q)\to(P\wedge Q)\\
&\equiv(P\wedge Q)\vee(\neg P\wedge\neg Q)\\
&\equiv(P\vee Q)\wedge(\neg P\vee\neg Q)
\end{align}

but all of these use both $P$ and $Q$ twice. (I allow $\wedge,\vee$ in the above because they can both be written in terms of $\to,\neg$ without any extra duplication of the variables: $$P\vee Q\equiv\neg P\to Q,\quad P\wedge Q\equiv\neg(P\to\neg Q).$$

Similarly, NAND and NOR can be expressed using the variables only once, but XOR can be so expressed iff the biconditional can, and that's the question. It is okay if one of the variables has to be duplicated, as long as the other one appears only once.

Comment: @AndreasBlass If you recall what you asked, I would say that the definition wouldn't have equivalence symbols. But that doesn't matter, because my answer wasn't correct with respect to its reasoning.

Comment: @Doug Who are you talking to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there exist such formula, it must be like this:
$$f(P,Q)\to g(Q)$$
where $P$ appears once in $f$, and, since it is equivalent to $P\leftrightarrow Q$, we have
$$\begin{align}
f(0,0)&\to g(0)\\
f(0,1)&\wedge\neg g(1)\\
f(1,0)&\wedge\neg g(0)\\
f(1,1)&\to g(1)
\end{align}$$

The 2nd and the 3rd formulas imply that $g(0)=g(1)=0$, that is, $g(Q)\equiv Q\wedge\neg Q$. Then $f(P,Q)\equiv \neg(P\leftrightarrow Q)$, so the formula $\neg f(P,Q)$ is a shorter one that verify the condition. That is, every formula that verifies the condition can be shortened.

This is a contradiction, so the formula that you are looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: Regarding the first sentence: It may be the case that the formula has a $\neg$ at the outermost level, or that the $P$ is on the right side of the implication.

Comment: If $P$ is on the right side, $g(Q)\to f(P,Q)$, the formula can be written $\neg f(P,Q)\to\neg g(Q)$. If it has a $\neg$ at the outermost level, the same reasoning leads to $f(P,Q)$, instead of $\neg f(P,Q)$.